# SQL case | If <value> then <SELECT>

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, select, case

I want to `SELECT` based on the user language (German or English) a value from a table. I know I can do the selection later in a PHP if/else but I want to try if I can do the selection already in my SQL query. I have seen in the documentation for SQL `CASE` no example or solution for my demands. I am not sure if this is possible. As I have seen only 'text' is accepted for `THEN` but no new SQL QUERY.

My SQL Query

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  
                              audit.id as audit_id, 
                              audit.questionaire_id, 
                              audit.assigned_auditor, 
                              audit.co_auditor_1_id, 
                              audit.co_auditor_2_id, 
                              audit.comment_positive, 
                              audit.comment_negative, 
                              audit.comment_general, 
                              audit.general_audit_status, 
                              audit.questionaire_id, 
                              audit.audit_date_start, 
                              audit.audit_date_end,
                              audit.audit_reason, 
                              audit.audited_process, 
                              audit.area,
                              departments.name,
                              departments.location,
                              suppliers.supplier_name, 
                              suppliers.supplier_country,
                              suppliers.supplier_city, 
                              users.vorname, 
                              users.nachname, 
                              users.email,    
                              questionaire.scheme,
                              questionaire.quest_name, //German translation
                              questionaire.quest_name_en // English translation
                              FROM audit 
                              LEFT JOIN suppliers
                              ON audit.supplier_id = suppliers.id 
                              LEFT JOIN users
                              ON audit.supplier_uid = users.id 
                              LEFT JOIN departments
                              ON audit.department = departments.id
                              JOIN questionaire
                              ON audit.questionaire_id = questionaire.id
                              WHERE audit.id = $id");

$result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$audit = $statement->fetch();
```

And here the section where I want to implement such a SQL `CASE` situation:

My attempt:

```sql
... things before ...
questionaire.scheme,
CASE users.language = 'de' THEN
(SELECT quest_name FROM questionaire WHERE id = audit.questionaire_id)
ELSE (SELECT quest_name_en FROM questionaire WHERE id = audit.questionaire_id)                              
FROM audit 
... things after ...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your queries references `audit` which is not defined.

Comment: There is no reason to do this in SQL. You have already defined tables and columns - just do it in your application code.

Comment: You can simplify your `CASE` statements to just `CASE users.language WHEN 'de' THEN quest_name_de  ELSE quest_name_en END AS quest_name` - there's no need for a `SELECT` subquery because you already have the `questionaire` table joined.

Comment: i have added my original query for your understanding and my idea below.

Comment: Put `WHEN` after the `CASE` like the syntax requires, and put `END` after the last closing bracket.

Comment: @Dai Thank you! This is working very well! Miracle solved :) ( I can not vote your comment, you need to create an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not need to be as complicated as your query already joins the necessary tables together.
So instead of

```
CASE users.language = 'de' THEN
(SELECT quest_name FROM questionaire WHERE id = audit.questionaire_id)
ELSE (SELECT quest_name_en FROM questionaire WHERE id = audit.questionaire_id)
```

use

```
CASE 
  WHEN users.language = 'de' THEN quest_name 
  ELSE quest_name_en 
END
```

This is the SQL I know for Oracle or SQL Server. In this type of CASE you can check multiple types as the condition is in the WHEN clause.

Alternative

```
CASE users.language
  WHEN 'de' THEN quest_name 
  ELSE quest_name_en 
END
```

In this CASE the type is pre-set by the CASE and therefore the WHEN can only evaluate against the same type. Like in this case only against strings.